# What is the most possible height when the binary search tree haw n nodes?

Tags: binary-search-tree

Is there a mathematical type for the most possible height of a tree with exactly n nodes?

Comment: The maximum height is n

Answer (score 0):

It can be anything. If you are not implementing a balanced binary search tree (like AVL tree or Red-Black tree), then the height of the tree will depend on the inputs you give. In the worst-case, height can be equal to the number of nodes(if each value is greater than the previous one or each value is less than the previous one). If you need more info, please consider describing the specific use case for which this question was asked.